# How to remove date from strptime and plot

Tags: r, time, plot

I have a variable, time, that is in Hour-Second-Minute format.

```
time <- "01:01:52"
```

I want to have a new time-format variable, time2.

I try:

```
strptime(db[1,10], format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

This returns

```
"2014-01-30 01:01:52"
```

How do I get rid of the Year-Month-Date portion of this?

I have absolutely no attachment to the "POSIXlt" or "POSIXt" classes.  I am trying to plot a bunch of times on a histogram.  Can I use ggplot2 to do so?  If not, what is the best way to plot times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ggplot2 scale_x_datetime example:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_datetime.html

the examples will show you ways to format as time only.